# Xml response in jmeter is showing html tag how to make it into proper xml

Tags: jmeter

Below is the Xml response which i get it for one of the request with html tag. How do I change this below xml with html tag in to proper xml format jmeter.

{"xml":"\r\n\r\n            .start-tag {\r\n              color: purple;\r\n              font-weight: bold;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .end-tag {\r\n              color: purple;\r\n              font-weight: bold;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .comment {\r\n              color: green;\r\n              font-style: italic;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .pi {\r\n              color: orchid;\r\n              font-style: italic;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .text {\r\n              font-weight: normal;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .attribute-name {\r\n              color: black;\r\n              font-weight: bold;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .attribute-value {\r\n              color: blue;\r\n              font-weight: normal;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            table {\r\n              border-spacing: 0;\r\n              margin: 0;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            td {\r\n              padding: 0;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .indent {\r\n              margin-left: 1em;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .expander-cell {\r\n              -moz-user-select: none;\r\n              -webkit-user-select: none;\r\n              -ms-user-select: none;\r\n              user-select: none;\r\n              vertical-align: top;\r\n              text-align: center;\r\n              width: 1em;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .expander-icon {\r\n              cursor: pointer;\r\n              font-weight: bold;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .expander-closed > * > .expander-content, .expander-closed > * > .expander-content ~ span {\r\n              display: none;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .comment {\r\n              font-family: monospace;\r\n              white-space: pre;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .long, .modal table span {\r\n              white-space: pre;\r\n            }\r\n\r\n            .modal table {\r\n              table-layout: fixed;\r\n              width: 100%;\r\n            }\r\n          \r\n\r\n              \r\n                $(document).ready(decorateCollapsibleMessageBody);\r\n              \r\n          \r\n\r\n\r\n<tr style="vertical-align: top; font-family: monospace;">\r\n<td style="width: 54px; padding-right: 12px;">\r\n<div style="overflow-x: hidden;">\r\n<table style="text-align: right;" class="lineNumbers">\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">RepositoryOperationRq <span class="attribute-name">xsi:schemaLocation<span class="markup">=<span class="attribute-value">"http://www.ACORD.org/Standards/AcordMsgSvc/1.4.0 Acord-Repository_v-1-2-0.xsd"<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">MsgId<span class="markup">><span class="text">43d4d02f-53ff-4822-8080-fc1e2acc10a4<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">MsgId<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">CreationDtTime<span class="markup">><span class="text">2021-08-05T11:26:34Z<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">CreationDtTime<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">RepositoryOperationTypeCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">RepositoryNotify<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">RepositoryOperationTypeCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">Sender<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyId<span class="markup">><span class="text">urn:duns:012345678<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyId<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyRoleCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">ServiceProvider<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyRoleCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyName<span class="markup">><span class="text">TIW<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyName<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">Sender<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">Receiver<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyId<span class="markup">><span class="text">urn:duns:236196819<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyId<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyRoleCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">ServiceProvider<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyRoleCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">PartyName<span class="markup">><span class="text">ACORD Solutions Group<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">PartyName<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">Receiver<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">Application<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">ApplicationCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">Jv-Ins-Reinsurance<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">ApplicationCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">SchemaVersion<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent text long">http://www.ACORD.org/standards/Jv-Ins-Reinsurance/2005-2\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">SchemaVersion<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">Application<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentList<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">HierarchySortIndicator<span class="markup">><span class="text">0<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">HierarchySortIndicator<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentItem<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">Document<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentId<span class="markup">><span class="text">279b1cf5-3132-491d-9198-e7d5674c9606<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentId<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentVersion<span class="markup">><span class="text">1<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentVersion<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentVersionDtTime<span class="markup">><span class="text">2018-04-01T12:00:00Z<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentVersionDtTime<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">FileId<span class="markup">><span class="text">SampleSecondReport.pdf<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">FileId<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">FileFormatCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">application/pdf<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">FileFormatCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">FileSize<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">NumUnits<span class="markup">><span class="text">331<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">NumUnits<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">UnitMeasurementCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">KB<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">UnitMeasurementCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">FileSize<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">DocumentTypeCd<span class="markup">><span class="text">report_loss_history<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentTypeCd<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">Document<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">rlc:ReferredObjects<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n\r\n\r\n<td class="expander-cell"><span class="expander-icon">-<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">rlc:Contract<span class="markup">>\r\n<div class="expander-content">\r\n<div class="indent">\r\n<span class="markup"><<span class="start-tag">rlc:BrokerReference<span class="markup">><span class="text">B0572AV203575<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">rlc:BrokerReference<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">rlc:Contract<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">rlc:ReferredObjects<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentItem<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">DocumentList<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<span class="markup"></<span class="end-tag">RepositoryOperationRq<span class="markup">>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not XML response, this is [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) response (malformed though)
2. If you want to extract the content from `xml` [key](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) of the JSON response you can add a [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) configured like:

   [image]

   and it will extract the content of the `xml` key into `${response}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), you can visualize it using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

   [image]

Comment: Not its xml only when checked in browser, but when we get the response from server in jmeter it show xml along with html tag.